# Slide menu to be closed when tab clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a jsfiddle of slide menu:

http://jsfiddle.net/fh6p4/

```
$('#button').toggle( 
function() {
    $('#right').animate({ left: 250 }, 'slow', function() {
        $('#button').html('Close');
    });
}, 
function() {
    $('#right').animate({ left: 0 }, 'slow', function() {
        $('#button').html('Menu');
    });
}
```

);

I need this menu to be closed when I click on item1, item2, etc. Is that possible?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fh6p4/3365/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fh6p4/3371/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this short jQuery snippet :-

```
$('#button, #menu > ul > li').click(function(){
    var $this = $('#button');
    $('#right').animate({ left: ($this.html() == 'Close' ? 0 : 250) },'slow', function(){
         $this.html($this.html() == 'Close' ? 'Menu' : 'Close');
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fh6p4/3371/)

OR

```
$('#button, #menu > ul > li').click(function(){
    var left = parseInt($('#right').css('left'));
    $('#right').animate({ left: (left == 250 ? 0 : 250) },'slow', function(){
          $('#button').html( left == 250 ? 'Menu' : 'Close');
     });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fh6p4/3378/)

Comment: it is short, but.. it's better to check menu visibility, not `Menu/Close` text inside button.

Comment: @teran..menu is always visible only it's `left` css property is either `0` or `250`

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible

```
$('#button, #menu ul li a').toggle( 
function() {
    $('#right').animate({ left: 250 }, 'slow', function() {
        $('#button').html('Close');
    });
}, 
function() {
    $('#right').animate({ left: 0 }, 'slow', function() {
        $('#button').html('Menu');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You catch event when click on menu item, and process close menu.

Here are my code yu can reference

```
$("#menu ul li a").click(function(){
    $('#right').animate({ left: 0 }, 'slow', function() {
    $('#button').html('Menu');
  });
});
```